# ejecutar archivo js desde un boton

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un archivo js que se ejecuta asi

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="archivo.js"></script>
```

> Lo que requiero es llamarlo desde un click de un boton

Comment: Podés hacer una función de ese archivo y en el evento `click` ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 1):

primero que nada creo que no tienes muy claro como funciona la inclusión de javascript en html. [Aquí](https://rolandocaldas.com/html5/como-incluir-javascript-en-html5) puedes ver una explicación bastante completa.

Una vez dicho esto, lo que intentas hacer no se puede o, mejor dicho, se puede hacer pero no como lo planteas.

Vamos primero con el fichero javascrip, que en este caso es **archivo.js**. En este fichero debe existir una función que ejecute en el evento **click** del botón:

```
function doSomething_Click() {
    alert('Click executed');
}
```

Por otro lado, debemos asignar la función al evento click del botón mediante *addEventListener*. Puedes ver más información [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
// Obtenemos el botón a partir de su id. En este caso lo llamaremos testButton
var button = document.getElementById('testButton');

// Registramos el evento
button.addEventListener('click', doSomething_Click);
```

Y con esto finalizamos con el fichero javascript. Ahora incluimos el código javascrip en tu html de la manera que ya lo haces, que es usando la etiqueta `<script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="archivo.js"></script>
```

Y por último, creamos el botón con el id *testButton* en el html:

```
<button id='testButton'>Test button</button>
```

Con esto ya podrás ejecutar la función *doSomething_Click()* en el evento click del botón *testButton*.

Espero haberte ayudado. Te dejo el código completo por aquí.

```js
// Obtenemos el botón a partir de su id. En este caso lo llamaremos testButton
var button = document.getElementById('testButton');

// Registramos el evento
button.addEventListener('click', doSomething_Click);

function doSomething_Click() {
    alert('Click executed');
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Click event test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='testButton'>Test button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

El atributo onclick de los inputs permite ejecutar funciones y/o código javascript.

```
<input id="prueba" type="button" value="pinchame" onclick="funcion_js()">
```

Creo que con eso te podría valer

Comment: De esta forma es posible hacerlo también, aunque no es lo más recomendado en navegadores modernos: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Referencia_DOM_de_Gecko/Eventos